# How can I add a custom css to hide the back button in google forms using Formfacade

Tags: css, hide, google-forms, back-button

I want to hide the back button in a questionare I made on Google Forms. I know there isn't an option to do so in Google Forms so I embedded my form to Formfacade which allows me to add a CSS code in order to hide the back button. The problem is I cant figure out what to write in the CSS code. I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

As the formFacade guide suggests, you should get the css class via inspector and just add the rule `display: none` or `opacity: 0` or `visibility: hidden` to that.

https://formfacade.com/website/modify-styles-using-css-in-google-forms.html